# using chr + rand to generate a random character (A-Z)

Tags: php

I'm using the following to generate a random character from A-Z, but it's occasionally generating the @ symbol. Any idea how to prevent this? Maybe the character range is incorrect?

```
$letter = chr(64+rand(0,26));
```

Comment: It really only is the base offset (`64`) being `1` too low, and then the range of added integers being `1` too high, given the changed base. If you want to avoid such mistakes, which can easily occur, simply use something like [`Random::alphaUppercaseString($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Random).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use this it's easier.

**Upper Case**

```
$letter = chr(rand(65,90));
```

**Lowercase**

```
$letter = chr(rand(97,122));
```

[ascii chart](http://www.asciitable.com/)

The code below generates a random alpha-numeric string of $length. You can see the numbers there for what you need.

```
function izrand($length = 32) {

                $random_string="";
                while(strlen($random_string)<$length && $length > 0) {
                        $randnum = mt_rand(0,61);
                        $random_string .= ($randnum < 10) ?
                                chr($randnum+48) : ($randnum < 36 ? 
                                        chr($randnum+55) : $randnum+61);
                 }
                return $random_string;
}
```

> update: 12/19/2015

Here is an updated version of the function above, it adds the ability to generate a random numeric key OR an alpha numeric key. To generate numeric, simply add 
the second paramater as `true`.

> Example Usage

`$randomNumber = izrand(32, true); // generates 32 digit number as string`
`$randomAlphaNumeric = izrand(); // generates 32 digit alpha numeric string`

> Typecast to Integer

If you want to typecast the number to integer, simply do this after you 
generate the number. NOTE: This will drop any leading zeros if they exist.

`$randomNumber = (int) $randomNumber;`

> izrand() v2

```
function izrand($length = 32, $numeric = false) {

    $random_string = "";
    while(strlen($random_string)<$length && $length > 0) {
        if($numeric === false) {
            $randnum = mt_rand(0,61);
            $random_string .= ($randnum < 10) ?
                chr($randnum+48) : ($randnum < 36 ? 
                    chr($randnum+55) : chr($randnum+61));
        } else {
            $randnum = mt_rand(0,9);
            $random_string .= chr($randnum+48);
        }
    }
    return $random_string;
}
```

Comment: You have an error in the last portion of the selector: `($randnum < 36 ? chr($randnum+55) : $randnum+61)` ... should be `($randnum < 36 ? chr($randnum+55) : chr($randnum+61))`...

Comment: Since PHP 7, `random_int` (a cryptographic RNG) should be used rather than `rand` or `mt_rand`.

Comment: To combine multiple ranges you could do something like this: `$a = [$randUpperCase, $randLowerCase, $randDigit];` and then get a random value from the array: `$randAlphaNum = $a[random_int(0, count($a) - 1)];`

Answer (score 4):

ASCII code 64 is `@`. You want to start at 65, which is `A`. Also, PHP's `rand` generates a number from `min` to `max` inclusive: you should set it to 25 so the biggest character you get is 90 (`Z`).

```
$letter = chr(65 + rand(0, 25));
```

Comment: why not just `chr(rand(65,90));'?

Answer (score 4):

```
$range = range('A', 'Z');
$index = array_rand($range);
echo $range[$index];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use, given you could generate from a-Z:

```
$range = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'),range('a', 'z'));
$index = array_rand($range, 1);
echo $range[$index];
```

Comment: rather than `range()`, why not `str_split()`? `echo array_rand(str_split('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'),1);`

Answer (score -1):

The below code will generate an alphanumric string of 2 letters and 3 digits.

```
$string = strtoupper(chr(rand(65, 90)) . chr(rand(65, 90)) . rand(100, 999));
echo $string;
```